# What does it mean when there's no explicit access modifier in Java?

Tags: java

So if you have a method prototype like `void myMethod()`. What does that mean? What kind of access does it grant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "package access".  Basically any class that shares the same package as your declaring class can see/use the method.  Subclasses cannot, unless they are in the same package as the superclass.

For more details, see here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 3):

This is the so-called "default" or "package" access level. Fields and methods with this access level may be accessed within the same class or by classes in the same package. This is different from "protected" because subclasses cannot access a "default" scope field if they are not in the same package. [See details here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 1):

it means that it is package private

in other words other classes in the same package can access it no-one else

Answer (score 0):

Package access; visible to everything within the enclosing package.

Answer (score 0):

Without access specifier the method is accessible from within the same package.